# PHP + MYSQL how to group the months by years

Tags: php, mysql, list

I need to create a grouped year / month list

- 2020

  - January
  - February
- 2019

  - May
  - June

My Table (name: reports)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSd5M.png)

Query

```
SELECT YEAR(report_date) as y, MONTH(report_date) as m, report_company_id 
FROM reports 
WHERE YEAR(report_date) = YEAR(report_date) AND report_company_id="11" 
GROUP BY y, m ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC
```

I need help with a script displaying the structure of the list

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show" id="tab-<?php echo $row['company_id']; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">    
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">    
    <?php 
        $count_month = $db -> query
        (
            'SELECT YEAR(report_date) as y, MONTH(report_date) as m, report_company_id
             FROM reports
             WHERE YEAR(report_date) = YEAR(report_date) AND report_company_id="'.$company_id.'"
             GROUP BY y, m
             ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC'
        );
        $last_year = 0;
        ?>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <?php 
        foreach ($count_month as $key) { ?>
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne-<?php echo $key['y']; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><?php echo $key['y']; ?></button>
            </div>
                <div id="collapseOne-<?php echo $key['y']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php echo $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $key['m'], 10)); // March ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>                        
    </div>                        
</div>
```

My result. year is repeated twice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAR7q.png)

Comment: If there is an issue with PHP please add the PHP code and explain the issue. Seems like an aggregation MySQL question.

Comment: This looks the same as your last question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178462/archive-years-month-using-php-mysql.

Comment: php code in the content post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you want 2nd level aggregation in visual then you need to convert your array to another associative array using year as key

```
   $count_month_map = Array();
    foreach ($count_month as $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($value['y'], $count_month_map)) {
            array_push($count_month_map[ $value['y'] ], $value);
        } else {
            $count_month_map[ $value['y'] ] = Array( $value );
        }
    }
    $last_year = 0;
    ?>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <?php 
    foreach ($count_month_map as $key => $value) { ?>
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne-<?php echo $key; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><?php echo $key; ?></button>
        </div>
    <?php
          foreach ($value as $key1) {
    ?>
            <div id="collapseOne-<?php echo $key1['y']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php echo $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $key1['m'], 10)); // March ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
```

Here  `$count_month_map` is another associative array formed from `$count_month`

Then inside the main loop you need to have a second loop to loop though the array of array

**Method 2:**

You can store the year in your loop in a dummy variable say `$curr`, at the end bracket you assign it to another dummy variable `$prev`

then conditionally you suppress the button

```
    $curr = '';
    $prev = '';
    ?>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <?php 
    foreach ($count_month as $key) {
    $curr = $key['y'];
    if($prev != $curr) {
    ?>
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne-<?php echo $key['y']; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><?php echo $key['y']; ?></button>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
            <div id="collapseOne-<?php echo $key['y']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php echo $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $key['m'], 10)); // March ?>
                </div>
            </div>

    <?php 
    $prev = $curr;  
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
```

**Note:** Method 2 only applicable for year column sorted, which you are already doing